# Rigify: Teeth controls not connected to the teeth

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm testing and weight painting my rig(I used Rigify that I customize) when I tried to move both the top and bottom row of teeth and they don't move at all. Both of teeth controls are not attached to the teeth as shown below: [image: Teeth controls not attached]

Now the teeth are group with the eyes, eyelashes, and eyebrows as I wanted to textured them on one UV map so its hard for me to just select to the top row and parent to the Teeth.T bone. the Teeth.T and B bones doesn't show up in DEF but in ORG they do but you can't edited those.

Anyone know how to attach the each control to each row of teeth? Blender I'm using is 2.79b

Comment: Not sure about 2.79, but I think you can select the ORG Teeth.T bone, check its "Deform" option, create a new vertex group with the exact same name and assign all top teeth vertices to it. Similar for bottom row.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that out and get back if it works.

Comment: EDIT(couldn't edit my other comment anymore):Hmm didn't work. Does it need to be rename ORG-teeth.T or DEF-teeth.T(I did this one and nothing happened)

Comment: Better not change the names, the only fundamental thing is to copy the name and paste it as Vertex group name. Bone has to have its "deform" option enabled. Capital case sensitive.

Comment: Oh I didn't change the bones names. I named the new vertex group the bones names but was asking if the names should be ORG or DEF for the vertex groups. EDIT: oh nvm I got it to work! Had to use ORG name for the vertex group. Thank you for the help.